# Correct naming for join model in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have two models:

```
BigHouse
```

and

```
User
```

I have a join table between `BigHouse` and User that holds a many-to-many relation.

This table is called `big_houses_users` - I want to know what is the proper way of: naming the model file as well as the class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using `has_and_belongs_to_many`, your join table should be called `big_houses_users`, however you do not need to create a class in your `app/models`.

The preferred approach is to use `has_many :through`. For this I don't believe their is a convention to naming the class. I usually go with a relationship that makes sense. In your case this could be something like `Residency`

Comment: I am using `has_many :through` but I still don't know what is the convention on naming the file as well as the class name.

Comment: As the second part of the answer states, I don't believe there is a convention. Check the documentation [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association), the example they use is an `Appointment` model for a join table between `Patient` and `Physician`

Comment: How does Rails know which table to use on that model?

Comment: Let's assume you went with the `Residency` model, this class will still inherit from `ActiveRecord::Base`, so the table should be called `residencies`, just like any other model